# Set Android Custom Font on Tab Title

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am trying to set a custom font to the titles ("Tab Item 1", "Tab Item 2",  "Tab Item 3") from the code below. I am really new to Android Studio and Java and am just learning by doing and kind materials that has been over the internet.

Assuming I have a font named "abc.ttf" already in my assets folder, how do I cahange the font for tab title? Below are my TabFragment.java

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    TabLayout mTabLayout;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static final int int_items = 3;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabbed_layout, null);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        mTabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new TabOneFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new TabTwoFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new TabThreeFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */



        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return "Tab Item 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Tab Item 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Tab Item 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my tabbed_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `CustomTabLayout` class which will drive from `Tablayout` Then use this `CustomTablayout` in `xml` instead of `Tablayout`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "your fonts"); // here you will provide fully qualified path for fonts
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(Tab tab) {
        super.addTab(tab);

        ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
        ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) mainView.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());

        int tabChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That's what you'd have to do in the xml.

```
<yourpackagename.CustomTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**EDIT**

This custom class

```
package com.ifavaz.kulli;

/**
 * Created by ifawaz on 12/11/16.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AmazingDayEveryday.ttf"); // here you will provide fully qualified path for fonts
    }

    @Override
    public void setupWithViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        if (mTypeface != null) {
            this.removeAllTabs();
            ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

            PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();

            for (int i = 0, count = adapter.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
                Tab tab = this.newTab();
                this.addTab(tab.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)));
                AppCompatTextView view = (AppCompatTextView) ((ViewGroup) slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(1);
                view.setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is working screenshot [image]

I hope this will help you

Comment: "Then use this CustomTablayout in xml instead of Tablayout"    .... How do I do that

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am trying to figure this out. In XML android:id="@+id/tabs" refers to "tabs". In the CustomTabLayout.java,  "public void addTab(Tab tab)" ... should the last "tab" be "tabs"? or is the code from you as is correct?

Comment: Just make changes to the xml as i has mentioned in answer. Also change Type of TabLayout to ```CustomTablayout mTabLayout;``` then ```mTabLayout = (CustomTablayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);``` it should work now.

Comment: yes, I have done all of this. still it is not working. there r no errors ...just font is not applied. tried different fonts too ...what am i doing wrong

Comment: please tell me how you mentioned the fonts in ```mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "your fonts");```

Comment: the font is in the assets folder which is in app/src/main/ folder. the name of the font is "abc.ttf" without quotes. so the code is (.getAssets(), " abc.ttf") i use similar codes with same font to set titles in my navigation drawer ... which works! but the tab titles dont!

Comment: its should be like this.```mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");```  create a assest folder then inside it create fonts folder then keep fonts in it. it will work then

Comment: Nop, still not wofking for me. Here is the full code  https://github.com/ifavaz/kulli

Comment: i'll clone it and would push the changed soon

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is working now. I override the ```setupWithViewPager``` and changed the fonts there. Now it is working. see the screen shot

Comment: Finally!!!. Thanks so much for this. Now I will Google like crazy to understand what just happened! :P

Comment: That's how you learn. Stick to basics and you will get to it. You must always explore the widget code for learning purpose. Always explore and it will make you pro. I have been there and done that but i am still learning

Comment: How did you know that tabs fonts can be change like this, also I'm only able to change font of one tab, I have two tabs

Answer (score 0):

**Shorter answer:** You don't need to create a custom TabLayout class, simply provide a theme to your TabLayout in the xml like below:

**xml file**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed"
android:background="@color/white"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:tabTextColor="@color/black"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.YourThemeName" <!-- This is the change -->
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**styles.xml file**

```
<style name="AppTheme.YourThemeName" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
</style>
```